# Unity Share Script Android to iOS

Tags: c#, ios, facebook, twitter, unity-game-engine

Everything works fine on Android but I dont know how to make it work for iOS, Please Help out.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System.IO;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class ShareMenu : MonoBehaviour
{   
    private bool isProcessing = false;
    public string AppLinkURL { get; set; }
    private string shareText = "Download This Game";
    private string gameLink = "Download the game on play store at " + "\nhttps://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.CrazyDrivers";
    public void shareImage()
    { 
        if (!isProcessing)
            StartCoroutine(ShareScreenshot());
    }

    private IEnumerator ShareScreenshot()
    {
        isProcessing = true;
        yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame();

        string destination = Path.Combine(Application.persistentDataPath, System.DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd-HHmmss") + ".png");
        Debug.Log(destination);

        if (!Application.isEditor)
        {
            AndroidJavaClass intentClass = new AndroidJavaClass("android.content.Intent");
            AndroidJavaObject intentObject = new AndroidJavaObject("android.content.Intent");
            intentObject.Call<AndroidJavaObject>("setAction", intentClass.GetStatic<string>("ACTION_SEND"));
            AndroidJavaClass uriClass = new AndroidJavaClass("android.net.Uri");
            intentObject.Call<AndroidJavaObject>("putExtra", intentClass.GetStatic<string>("EXTRA_TEXT"), shareText + gameLink);
            intentObject.Call<AndroidJavaObject>("setType", "text/plain");
            AndroidJavaClass unity = new AndroidJavaClass("com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer");
            AndroidJavaObject currentActivity = unity.GetStatic<AndroidJavaObject>("currentActivity");
            currentActivity.Call("startActivity", intentObject);

            isProcessing = false;
        }
    }  
}
```

Can you somehow help me to change this code for ios
to let me share to facebook, twitter, whatsapp. Because on android it works very well. I am newbie to programming.

Comment: What happens when you try to deploy on iOS?

Comment: @SP. It just closes app,and sometimes it freezes

Answer (score 1):

I think the app crashed because you use `AndroidJavaClass` on iOS device.
You can try this.

```
#if !UNITY_EDITOR && UNITY_ANDROID
                AndroidJavaClass intentClass = new AndroidJavaClass("android.content.Intent");
                AndroidJavaObject intentObject = new AndroidJavaObject("android.content.Intent");
                intentObject.Call<AndroidJavaObject>("setAction", intentClass.GetStatic<string>("ACTION_SEND"));
                AndroidJavaClass uriClass = new AndroidJavaClass("android.net.Uri");
                intentObject.Call<AndroidJavaObject>("putExtra", intentClass.GetStatic<string>("EXTRA_TEXT"), shareText + gameLink);
                intentObject.Call<AndroidJavaObject>("setType", "text/plain");
                AndroidJavaClass unity = new AndroidJavaClass("com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer");
                AndroidJavaObject currentActivity = unity.GetStatic<AndroidJavaObject>("currentActivity");
                currentActivity.Call("startActivity", intentObject);

                isProcessing = false;
#elif UNITY_IOS
                //put iOS share code here
#endif
```

if your app stop crashing(but it will do nothing. because we only allow it to run on android device).Then, you can look for iOS implementation.
For iOS code you may look for more here http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/is-it-really-that-hard-to-share-a-simple-score-on-facebook-and-twitter-natively.231390/

for facebook(only) you should use official Facebook Unity SDK
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/unity/
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/unity/reference/current/FB.FeedShare

Comment: I used share bunch unity , i can now share to facebook ,twitter,etc on IOs and android  , but dont know how to change something there , i want to share game link ,and score . but dont know how